# Prevent the user from navigating to a certain route url

Tags: url-routing, durandal

I have some main navigation buttons at the top of my SPA. Below in the content area I have some buttons for each of the main buttons. On of those content buttons loads a wizard which consists of 3 views. That means the user navigates at first to view1 clicks the next button to  navigate to view2 then navigate to view3 when all validations succeeded.

Now when I setup for all my viewModels/views a route then the user can navigate directly to view3 which would bypass my validations.

Maybe you say now, that I should not create a route for these views, but then I can not navigate to them either...

So how can I setup a route for view2 and view3 which should not be exposed directly to the user but I need to be able to navigate to them if view1 has bypassed the validation?

I have found info about durandaljs and preventing navigation to a certain url:

· Added a guardRoute hook to the router to allow, deny or redirect based on the route.

But I have no idea how to use the guardRoute in my own viewmodels...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a question close to this one on [Durandal's newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/durandaljs/wizard/durandaljs/U6yH1Gw8Y_M/GJmZsArYz4cJ) a while ago.

In short instead of using router functionality use ViewModel.activator() to switch between those steps. That way you are in complete control, which steps are accessible depending on the state of your Wizard VM.

Here's Rob's recommendation from the thread above:

> Compose, compose, compose. :)  If I were building a wizard, here's
> what I would do:
>
> 1. Create a module that manages the current page and transitioning next/back. Create a view for it that uses compose to bring in the
>    current page
> 2. Create a module for each step of the wizard, that has it's unique fields and validation.
> 3. Create a view for each module step.
>
> That's all there is to it. Something like this:

#### Updated example:

Live version : http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-1.2/#/view-composition/wizard

```
define(['durandal/viewModel', './step1', './step2', './step3'], function( viewModel, Step1, Step2, Step3 ) {

    var steps = [new Step1(), new Step2(), new Step3()];
    var step = ko.observable(0);
    var activeStep = viewModel.activator();
    var stepsLength = steps.length;

    var hasPrevious = ko.computed(function() {
        return step() > 0;
    });

    var hasNext = ko.computed(function() {
        return (step() < stepsLength - 1);
    });

    // Start with first step
    activeStep(steps[step()]);

    return {
        showCodeUrl: true,
        steps: steps,
        step: step,
        activeStep: activeStep,
        next: next,
        previous: previous,
        hasPrevious: hasPrevious,
        hasNext: hasNext
    };

    function next () {
        if ( step() < stepsLength ) {
            step(step() + 1);
            activeStep(steps[step()]);
        }
    }

    function previous () {
        if ( step() > 0 ) {
            step(step() - 1);
            activeStep(steps[step()]);
        }
    }

});
```

Checkout out the whole thread for more information.

Comment: How does this solve the problem of entering #/view2 in the url bar and so skipping view1 ? Does this implicity mean I should create a validated proeprty for each step1/2/3 and when the user loads #/view2 I will check for the validation value and navigate to view1 then if the validation is not succeeded?

Comment: Router navigation is completely optional to Durandal so there's no need to define a route to your step views. The wizard uses `viewModel.activator()` instead to switch to the correct vm/view.

Comment: @Elisa: I've created an example and updated the answer above. `hasPrevious|hasNext` and `next|previous` could/should be enhanced to implement the wizard specific logic.

Comment: you rock! Just what I needed! I will read it the next days more exhaustively also the other links on the site. Thanks a bunch. Ok no router for the step views that makes sense if there is a way to navigate programatically.

Comment: @Elisa Glad you find it useful. [dFiddle](https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2) is work in progress. Fork it, clone it, use it as test ground... and send pull requests whenever you've want to share something :).

Comment: Is this assumption correct: In your wizard/index.js script you handle the Next_button logic for the next step1.js Should this index.js file also contain the next_logic for all steps or can I put each next_logic in its own step.js file? I have not seen you doing this but I assume that would be the correct approach having multiple different views/viewModels right?

Comment: I am asking this because when I look at the step1.html, step2.html etc... I can not see any next button inside there so it seems the index.js is driving the whole logic for every view and viewmodel concerning next and previous. I prefer that each viewmodel decides when to go forth or back.

Comment: The wizard is responsible for the state and navigation of all steps. It has instances of all step vms, so each step can have its own logic, which is then evaluated by the wizard. e.g. in a simple case (like next|previous) one `isValid` observable per step might do it.